# Prove that the $\sum_{x=1}^{n} \cos^2(x)$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I need to show that $$\sum_{x=1}^{n} \cos^2(x)$$ is bounded above. I know that there's a similar formula for $$\sum_{x=1}^{n} \sin(2x)$$ but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Not sure what you try to mean with your second expression since it's the same as the first.

Comment: Sorry, the second sum was a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: So do you know the second sum or looking for it?

Comment: @Gevorg Hmayakyan I know it. I'm trying to find the upper bound on the first sum.

Comment: @Brahadeesh It's a finite sum.

Comment: So the second sum equals $\frac{\sin(n) \sin(1 + n)}{\sin(1)}$

Comment: The exact sum for the first one is $\frac{(2 n-1)}{4} + \frac{\sin(1 + 2 n)}{4\sin(1)}$

Comment: Can you calculate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos^2(k) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos(2k)+1}{2}=\frac 12(n+\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(2k))\\
&=\frac 12(n+Re(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{2ik})) = \frac 12(n+Re(e^{2i}\frac{e^{2in}-1}{e^{2i}-1}))\end{align}$$

Note that $\left|Re(e^{2i}\frac{e^{2in}-1}{e^{2i}-1})\right|\leq \frac{2}{|e^{2i}-1|}$, hence $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos^2(k) = \frac n2 + O(1)$$

This implies the sum is not bounded.